# How do you Format a Typescript Document in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: typescript, formatting, visual-studio-code, code-formatting

I tried a few different plugins but can't manage to find a way to properly format the same way sublime can. Example result after formatting.  I'd like to keep the properties in the same line if possible.  Thanks.

VScode

[image]

Sublime
[image]

Comment: This really has nothing to do with Angular 2.

Comment: Thanks.  I removed the tag.

Answer (score 3):

Ok my bad! It was a plugin conflicting with the editor's own formatting tool.  I uninstalled plugins one by one and found that the beautify plugin was the issue.  Turns out VScode is pretty good out of the box.  I used Sublime for a while and anytime I installed it I always went straight for the prettifiers, beautifiers, etc.  Force of habit I guess.

Comment: CLang-format plugin was overriding the builtin for TypeScript which was giving lot of Tslint warnings

Comment: This helps to me. Hope you can accept the answer no?